# Issue with loading python matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

This is the error I am getting:

> ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not
>   found (required by
>   /home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/../../.././libpng16.so.16)

Comment: Please add some context to this question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: Show your codes too

Comment: Problem solved. It turned out that my version of libpng was looking for the older version of zlib. I reinstalled(updated) libpng and things are working correctly now.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. The question contains enough information to figure out what is wrong and suggest a solution. Good to know that you were able to solve it by yourself.

Comment: Since you have found a solution, you can submit your own answer and accept it. You will not get any reputation points for doing so, but it could help others in the future.

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid ! It's my first time to ask a question here and I wasn't very familiar about the process. Now I know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For context for the question, I am going to add, I was upgrading my python 2 software that generates statistic plots with matplotlib for mod-wsgi web apps. My httpd log was showing the ZLIB import error. I had the same error for my non-webapp errors. I found the question and answer here, and decided to upgrade and then downgrade packages. My answer is submitted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It turned out that my version of libpng was looking for the older version of zlib. I reinstalled(updated) libpng and things are working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

For my conda environment 4.5.11 (miniconda2), I had the same error `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found.. etc..  /site-packages/matplotlib/../../.././libpng16.so.16). I was not able upgrade, since 1.16.35 was not yet available from conda. For my solution, I kept downgrading libpng to version 1.6.30, and downgraded matplotlib=2.0.2.

I do not like downgrading, however, to keep my operational environment to work, it was necessary. I am trying to automate my deployments and was not happy that I had to manually intervene. I like using conda, since it typically manages the matplotlib install very well, however, it the nature of the beast for open source to have upgrade/downgrade issues.

In conclusion, ZLIB is really not the issue, but what versions of matplotlib you are running. You just have to try upgrading and downgrading packages to get a good fit for matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, I also encountered the same problem, so I report the solution in case it can help someone.

It appeared to be some incompatibilities between pyqtgraph and matplotlib. Importing matplotlib before pyqtgraph solved the problem.

```
matplotlib version: '3.3.1'
pyqtgraph version: '0.11.0'
```